# React-select does not show the selected value in the field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange, react-select

i have a react-select component which i define like this:

```
<Select
            id="portf"
            options={opts}
            onChange={value => portfolioSelector(value)}
            placeholder="Select Portfolio"
          />
```

with `opts = [{label: any, value:1}, {label:Two, value:2}]`.

The values when selected are stored in the state via `portfolioSelector` function. The problem is that when i select a value it wasn't show in the select field. My main component is this:

```
const PortfolioSelector = ({
  opts,
  portfolioSelector
}) => {
  if (opts) {
    return (
      <div className="portfolio select-box">
        <label htmlFor="selectBox" className="select-box__label">
        Portfolio
        </label>
        <div className="select-box__container">
          <Select
            id="portf"
            options={opts}
            onChange={value => portfolioSelector(value)}
            placeholder="Select Portfolio"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="separator" />
      </div>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div>Loading</div>
  );
};
```

Do you know why?

Comment: Can you show, how are you passing the portfolioSelector function

Comment: I make it a props via the container of this component. Let me show you: const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (
  {
    portfolioSelector: (currentPortfolio) => {
      dispatch(portfolioSelector(currentPortfolio));
    }
  }
);

Comment: i think your `onChange={value => portfolioSelector(value)}` needs to be `onChange={event => portfolioSelector(event.target.value)}`

Comment: I make this change before but it didn't work...

Comment: Without knowing the inner workings of the Select - where do you give it the currently selected value? You only specify options and an onChange but not what it should render as selected value.

Comment: you say that i must add an onSelect={event=> portfolioSelector(event.target.value)} needs to be onChange={value => portfolioSelector(value)} ?

Comment: i think you need to assign the value like this: `value={/*value passed in onchange/*}` to Select.

Comment: Excuse me but i dont undestand. value = {portfolioSelector(value)}?

Comment: You need to maintain the value of the selector in the state and then bind it with the value property of the select field.

Comment: My component is stateless as i described. it does not hold any state

Comment: you are using `function` to pass the `value` to parent component, from parent component itself pass the `value` to child in `props` also, and assign the value to `Select`, like this: `value={props.value}`.

Comment: It didnt work either.. :(

Answer (score 17):

This is an alternative solution that i used.

**Demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/github/mkaya95/React-Select_Set_Value_Example

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

export default function App() {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState("none");
  const options = [
    { value: "none", label: "Empty" },
    { value: "left", label: "Open Left" },
    { value: "right", label: "Open Right" },
    {
      value: "tilt,left",
      label: "Tilf and Open Left"
    },
    {
      value: "tilt,right",
      label: "Tilf and Open Right"
    }
  ];
  const handleTypeSelect = e => {
    setSelectedOption(e.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Select
        options={options}
        onChange={handleTypeSelect}
        value={options.filter(function(option) {
          return option.value === selectedOption;
        })}
        label="Single select"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Not working for `groupedOptions`

Comment: This works for some reason.

Answer (score 11):

The `value` is handled really bad, and it needs hacks like [here](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/2674#issuecomment-458374593), explained [here](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/2674#issuecomment-466046110).

Long story short; the `value` works differently. You'd expect

`value={MY_VALUE}`, but it works instead

`value={{label: MY_VALUE}}`.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Danielecki for pointing me to the right direction. You really saved my day. Just a heads up my solution was this: `<Select ... value={{label: permittedValues[value], value}} options={options}></Select>` it seems that you will need to add the `label` AND the `value` as an object. Just the label as the value didn't work for me :(

Answer (score 9):

```
<Select
options={this.props.locale}
onChange={this.selectCountryCode}
value={{label : this.state.selectedCountryLabel}}
/>
```

The value property expects the shape Array.

Comment: Easiest solution of all. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 4):

First thing is you are created the wrong array, if label: any or Two is string you have to add double quote.
Look at this:

```
opts = [{label: "any", value:1}, {label:"Two", value:2}]
```

Second, You must remember the options in this case is opts is an array of object which have  label and value, what the data you want to add to your state?

```
      <Select
        id="portf"
        options={opts}
        onChange={value => portfolioSelector(value.value /* or if you want to add label*/ value.label)}
        placeholder="Select Portfolio"
      />
```

Comment: I want to add the value data in my state. But, this functionality is working correctly. The value is stored in my state. The problem is that i cant see the selected value in the portfolio input. I think your answer is not what i'm looking but thanks a lot :)

Comment: can you give me screeshot result of your select input.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply put the value property as `Selected.label`

```
value={selectedOption.label}
```

Answer (score 2):

For any one who is facing problems with React-Select getting populated or React-select doesn't get selected value; try to give it a dynamic key attribute who changes every time your data changes (either options array or selected option), so it will re-render with new data.

Answer (score 1):

[I fixed it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcV6s.png)
You forgot add value property. Use this, check the working code:

```
const opts = [{ label: 'any', value: 1 }, { label: 'Two', value: 2 }];

const PortfolioSelector = ({ options }) => {
  if (options) {
    return (
      <div className="portfolio select-box">
        <label htmlFor="selectBox" className="select-box__label">
          Portfolio
        </label>
        <div className="select-box__container">
          <Select
            id="portf"
            options={options}
            value={this.state.opts1}
            onChange={value => this.setState({ opts1: value })}
            placeholder="Select Portfolio" />
        </div>
        <div className="separator" />
      </div>
    );
  }
  return <div>Loading</div>;
};
```

and call your component

```
<PortfolioSelector options={opts} />
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-rgb-o5svh?file=/src/App.js

code:

```js
import axios from 'axios'
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import Select from 'react-select'
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState()
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState()

  useEffect(()=>{
    const getUsers = async () => {
      const {data} = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      setUsers(data)
    }
    getUsers()
  },[])
const options = users && users.map(user =>{
  return {label: user.name, value: user.id}
})
console.log(userId)
  return (
    <div className="App">
     {users && (
       <Select 
       placeholder='Select user...'
       isSearchable
       value={options.label}
       options={options}
       onChange={(option) => setUserId(option.value) }
       />
     )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide lable and value object together like `{label: ?, value: ?}`

```
const selectedValue = options.find(x => x.value===value);
<Select
    id="portf"
    options={opts}
    onChange={value => portfolioSelector(value)}
    placeholder="Select Portfolio"
    value={label : selectedValue.label, value: (value ? selectedValue.value : "")}
/>
```

Answer (score -6):

```
opts = [{label: any, value:1}, {label:Two, value:2}]
```

value must be string.

Comment: No, `value` will be treated as a string automatically. This answer does not add anything meaningful to the answer, and if anything, should be written as a comment.